# Set GCC path in makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

Whenever I am building my package it uses `/usr/bin/g++` (system compiler). 
I want to build my package with C++11 constructs. I have tried `-std=c++11` option but with system compiler it says unrecognized option.
I want to build my package from a different `gcc` compiler which will get downloaded as part of my package dependency.

So, how can I specify the location of `gcc` compiler in Makefile?

Comment: See [the `CC` and `CXX` implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)

Comment: @考えネロク How to set? is that by export command ?

Comment: It can be simply set inside the makefile.

Comment: Have you tried devtoolset ?

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are looking for:

1. Setting the environment variable `CXX` just for the process that will run `make`:

   ```
   $ CXX=/path-to-your-compiler/g++ make
   ```
2. Exporting the environment variable `CXX` in your shell:

   ```
   $ CXX=/path-to-your-compiler/g++
   $ export CXX
   $ make
   ```
3. Setting `CXX` at `make`'s command-line:

   ```
   $ make CXX=/path-to-your-compiler/g++
   ```
4. Inside your makefile:

   ```
   CXX := /path-to-your-compiler/g++
   ```

Note that setting the variable at `make`'s command line overrides the other values, and variables set inside the makefile override the ones obtained from the environment (unless the command-line option `-e` or `--environment-overrides` is provided).

Inside your makefile, you can still override any value set by other means by using the [`override`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html) directive:

```
override CXX := /path-to-your-compiler/g++
```

Comment: Can I set the path based on machine arch (32 or 64) in makefile?

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Based on the targeted arch or the arch of the machine?

Comment: Anyway, useful stuff: [conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html#Conditional-Example)

Comment: After setting up the path i am getting Shared library missing exception "cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: It seems to be a different issue, I would suggest you to create a fresh new question with the actual contents of your makefile.